# Deploying Jekyll to GitHub pages takes more time to reflect on the main server

Tags: github, jekyll

I've been recently trying out Jekyll. Everything works fine. I've deployed my initial site successfully but, after then while I'm trying to commit and push everything looks good and reflected in the repository page, but on the main pages.

I'm pushing only the deployment files from the `_source` folder in the main branch.

**UPDATE**: The changes are now shown. But, why it takes so much time to do that? Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually takes up to 10 minutes for the pages to get updated as described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually).

> Tip: After the first push, it can take up to ten minutes before the content is available.